# select dropdown in angularjs UI grid column not working for external editcellTemplate

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I created a dropdown inside a column of angularJS UI grid. Infact I took the same example as there in UI grid tutorial.ref:http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/201_editable
. Here I modified to apply my own template(partial.html) for editableCelltemplate . When I change the drop down value, it's not captured.
app.js
http://plnkr.co/edit/UMsOeeETHxbMMdZQry90?p=preview

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngTouch', 'ui.grid', 'ui.grid.edit', 'addressFormatter']);
 
angular.module('addressFormatter', []).filter('address', function () {
  return function (input) {
      return input.street + ', ' + input.city + ', ' + input.state + ', ' + input.zip;
  };
});
 
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
  $scope.gridOptions = {  };
  $scope.editDropdownOptionsArrayValue = [{id:1, gender:'male'},
        {id:1, gender:'male'}
     ];
 
  $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = [
    { name: 'id', enableCellEdit: false, width: '10%' },
    { name: 'name', displayName: 'Name (editable)', width: '20%' },
    { name: 'age', displayName: 'Age' , type: 'number', width: '10%' },
    { name: 'gender', displayName: 'Gender', editableCellTemplate: 'partial.html', width: '20%',
      cellFilter: 'mapGender', editDropdownValueLabel: 'gender', editDropdownOptionsArray: $scope.editDropdownOptionsArrayValue},
    { name: 'registered', displayName: 'Registered' , type: 'date', cellFilter: 'date:"yyyy-MM-dd"', width: '20%' },
    { name: 'address', displayName: 'Address', type: 'object', cellFilter: 'address', width: '30%' },
    { name: 'address.city', displayName: 'Address (even rows editable)', width: '20%',
         cellEditableCondition: function($scope){
         return $scope.rowRenderIndex%2
         }
    },
    { name: 'isActive', displayName: 'Active', type: 'boolean', width: '10%' },
    { name: 'pet', displayName: 'Pet', width: '20%', editableCellTemplate: 'ui-grid/dropdownEditor',
      editDropdownRowEntityOptionsArrayPath: 'foo.bar[0].options', editDropdownIdLabel: 'value'
    }
  ];
 
 
 
 $scope.msg = {};
 
 $scope.gridOptions.onRegisterApi = function(gridApi){
          //set gridApi on scope
          $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
          gridApi.edit.on.afterCellEdit($scope,function(rowEntity, colDef, newValue, oldValue){
            $scope.msg.lastCellEdited = 'edited row id:' + rowEntity.id + ' Column:' + colDef.name + ' newValue:' + newValue + ' oldValue:' + oldValue ;
            $scope.$apply();
          });
        };
 
  $http.get('/data/500_complex.json')
    .success(function(data) {
      for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        data[i].registered = new Date(data[i].registered);
        data[i].gender = data[i].gender==='male' ? 1 : 2;
        if (i % 2) {
          data[i].pet = 'fish'
          data[i].foo = {bar: [{baz: 2, options: [{value: 'fish'}, {value: 'hamster'}]}]}
        }
        else {
          data[i].pet = 'dog'
          data[i].foo = {bar: [{baz: 2, options: [{value: 'dog'}, {value: 'cat'}]}]}
        }
      }
      $scope.gridOptions.data = data;
    });
}])
 
.filter('mapGender', function() {
  var genderHash = {
    1: 'male',
    2: 'female'
  };
 
  return function(input) {
    if (!input){
      return '';
    } else {
      return genderHash[input];
    }
  };
})
;
```

```css
.grid {
  width: 600px;
  height: 450px;
}
```

```html
<select ng-model="gender" data-ng-options="d as d.gender for d in grid.appScope.editDropdownOptionsArrayValue">
<option value="" selected="selected">select</option>
</select>
```

you can see when I change dropdown value the

```
gridApi.edit.on.afterCellEdit($scope,function(rowEntity, colDef, newValue, oldValue){
            $scope.msg.lastCellEdited = 'edited row id:' + rowEntity.id + ' Column:' + colDef.name + ' newValue:' + newValue + ' oldValue:' + oldValue ;
            $scope.$apply();
```

is not getting executed.

The same is getting executed in I apply editableCellTemplate: 'ui-grid/dropdownEditor' the default template. But in case of custome it's not executed. Any workaround/solution/pointer will really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In order to have a custom editor you need to write a directive and provide the events that the editable feature hooks onto - the end cell edit etc.  I wrote the original dropdown editor for ui-grid, which was a bit of fiddling around.  The commit that included it is here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/pull/1561, which will give some idea of the bits and pieces that are required to make it work.  (there's some mention of this in the editable tutorial).